# Laravel 5.4 Native Query runs properly on MY SQL server but not by Laravel Eloquent Query Builder. What I am doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.4. I am written query with Laravel eloquent. It's working properly when I manually write query into MySQL server, but Tt's not working when i code same query by Laravel Eloquent.

Please help...

Laravel Code

```
$dateS = new Carbon($req->fromDate);
$dateE = new Carbon($req->toDate);

$tasks = DB::table('taskday')->selectRaw("taskday.dayID, taskday.task_date, taskday.fk_userID, userdetails.fullname, count(assignedtask.fk_dayID) as total")
            ->join("assignedtask","assignedtask.fk_dayID","taskday.dayID")
            ->join("userdetails","userdetails.userID","taskday.fk_userID")
            ->whereBetween("taskday.task_date", [$dateS->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00", $dateE->format('Y-m-d')." 23:59:59"]);
if($req->staffname > 0){
    $tasks = $tasks->where('taskday.fk_userID',$req->staffname);
}

$tasks = $tasks->groupBy("assignedtask.fk_dayID")->get();

return $tasks;
```

My SQL Query

```
select `taskday`.`dayID`, `taskday`.`task_date`, `taskday`.`fk_userID`, `userdetails`.`fullname`, count(`assignedtask`.`fk_dayID`) as total 
from `taskday` inner join `assignedtask` on `assignedtask`.`fk_dayID` = `taskday`.`dayID` 
inner join `userdetails` on `userdetails`.`userID` = `taskday`.`fk_userID` 
where `taskday`.`task_date` between '2018-11-01 00:00:00' and '2018-12-19 23:59:59' 
group by `assignedtask`.`fk_dayID`
```

After fire query on mysql directly it's giving correct result

```
dayID    task_date   fk_userID   fullname    total
-------- ----------  ----------  ----------  -------------
DAY021   2018-12-02  USR300920   Manish      2
DAY022   2018-12-03  USR300924   Rovio       3
```

Laravel gives error

```
(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'medical.taskday.dayID'
 isn't in GROUP BY 
(SQL: select taskday.dayID, taskday.task_date, taskday.fk_userID, userdetails.fullname, count(assignedtask.fk_dayID) as total 
from `taskday` inner join `assignedtask` on `assignedtask`.`fk_dayID` = `taskday`.`dayID` 
inner join `userdetails` on `userdetails`.`userID` = `taskday`.`fk_userID` 
where `taskday`.`task_date` 
between 2018-11-01 00:00:00 and 2018-12-19 23:59:59 
group by `assignedtask`.`fk_dayID`)
```

Please help

Comment: In `config/database.php`, try setting `strict` to `false` on your active connection.

Comment: @TimLewis I was about to type the same thing. :D

Comment: no not working.. :(

Comment: Is your config cached? You'll have to run `php artisan config:cache` if so.

Comment: add the column `medical.taskday.dayID` to your `->groupBy(...`

Comment: Thank you @TimLewis... thank sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is actually raised for Cache. After clean all the cache, It starts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if I understood your question.

**Controller**

```
$dateS = new Carbon($req->fromDate);
$dateE = new Carbon($req->toDate);

$tasks = DB::table('taskday')
    ->where('taskday.task_date')
    ->selectRaw("taskday.dayID, taskday.task_date, taskday.fk_userID, userdetails.fullname, count(assignedtask.fk_dayID) as total")
    ->join('assignedtask.fk_dayID', 'assignedtask', '=', 'taskday.dayID')
    ->join('userdetails.userID', 'userdetails', '=', 'taskday.fk_userID')
    ->whereBetween('taskday.task_date', [date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($dateS)), date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($dateE))])
    ->groupBy('assignedtask.fk_dayID')
    ->get();

if($req->staffname > 0){
    $tasks = $tasks->where('taskday.fk_userID',$req->staffname);
}

$tasks = $tasks->groupBy("assignedtask.fk_dayID")->get();

return $tasks;
```

Please check your timestamp format in DB, it must same with this
or try to use Unixtime format on query of "whereBetween" for more accurate calculation.

**View**

```
. . .
   <tr>
     <th>dayID</th>
     <th>task_date</th>
     <th>fk_userID</th>
     <th>fullname</th>
     <th>total</t>
   </tr>
@foreach($tasks as $task)
   </tr>
     <td>$task->dayID</td>
     <td>$task->task_date</td>
     <td>$task->fk_userID</td>
     <td>$task->fullname</td>
     <td>$task->total</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
. . .
```

for the peace of coding :)